# Rasa chatbot giving a different response each time the same question is asked

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

I have trained a rasa chatbot on faq data.I have trained the bot similar to how it has been shown in this link(https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/). The issue with the bot is that it is giving different answer every time for the same question.Any fixes for this issue?

Comment: What questions are you asking? Can you post it here?

Comment: Same question only. My bot is giving different answers when I ask the same question multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging suggestions:

- check which policy is being used to make each prediction. If you see a machine learning policy kicking in, check your policies and stories.
- make sure you have the memoization policy in your config, and that its `max_history` parameter makes sense for your stories. If you are building a purely FAQ bot, this should probably be 1. E.g.

```
language: en
pipeline:
 - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
 - name: RegexFeaturizer
 - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
 - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
 - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
   analyzer: "char_wb"
   min_ngram: 1
   max_ngram: 4
 - name: DIETClassifier
   epochs: 100
 - name: EntitySynonymMapper
 - name: ResponseSelector
   epochs: 100

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
 - name: MemoizationPolicy
   max_history: 1
 - name: TEDPolicy
   epochs: 100
 - name: MappingPolicy
```

Comment: My nlu_config.yml file just has this(`language: en
pipeline: tensorflow_embedding`) as of now. This is in sync with whatever pipelines have mentioned for my rasa version. Please find it here https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.14.0/choosing_pipeline/

Comment: Where can I add the memoization policy ?

Comment: In rasa >1.0 you should have just one `config.yml` with a `pipeline` section for NLU and a  `policies` section for dialogue management. This is where you'd put the `MemoizationPolicy`. Try starting out with the pipeline produced by running `rasa init` (I've updated the answer with an example) and set `max_history` high enough to account for the longest pattern in your stories (default is 5, that might be high enough). When you say "different answer" you are referring to an actual bot response right, not just intent prediction? Because that would be a different issue

Comment: I see you are linking to a very old version of rasa -  it would be best to upgrade to the latest version of rasa (or at least rasa 1.7 if not 1.8)